# Php Query In loop not updating database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am using jquery and ajax to have a drag and drop sortable table.

My problem is that it only works about 10 percent of the time.

Here is my js code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// When the document is ready set up our sortable with it's inherant function(s)
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test-list").sortable({
        handle : '.handle',
        update : function () {
            var order = $('#test-list').sortable('serialize'); 
            $("#info").load("tow_sort2.php?"+order);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the tow_sort2.php page:

```
<?php 
include("../_includes/db_connection.php");

/**
 * This is where you would inject your sql into the database 
 * but we're just going to format it and send it back 
 */ 
$array =array();
foreach ($_GET['listItem'] as $position => $item)
{
  $sql = "UPDATE tow SET tow_order = '$position' WHERE tow_id = '$item'"; 
  $conn->query($sql);
  $array[] = $sql;
}
print_r($array);
?>
```

Here is the array that is being printed:

```
Array ( [0] => UPDATE tow SET tow_order = '0' WHERE tow_id = '5924' [1] => UPDATE tow SET tow_order = '1' WHERE tow_id = '5925' [2] => UPDATE tow SET tow_order = '2' WHERE tow_id = '5922' [3] => UPDATE tow SET tow_order = '3' WHERE tow_id = '5923' )
```

[Screenshot of the Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jQDY.jpg)

Comment: Do you get any error messages when it doesn't work?

Comment: What is the database provider? How are transaction managed?

Comment: What is the intended behavior?  How exactly is it not working?

Comment: No error messages occur.

Comment: The intended behavior is for it to change the order number in the database.

Comment: I think you should switch `$position` and `$item` in your query, i.e. to become: `$sql = "UPDATE tow SET tow_order = '$item' WHERE tow_id = '$position'";`

Comment: You should be using prepared statements for this sort of thing, or else anyone could change the `$_GET` parameters to delete everything from your database. If your database updates are not working correctly, then we'll need to see what errors they're producing in order to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using the method query instead of exec:

```
$conn->exec($sql);
```

By the way, your code is vurlnerable to sql injection. Please use [prepared](http://php.net/manual/fr/pdo.prepare.php) statement instead or check the variables.